# C++ If statement misbehaving

Tags: c++, if-statement, user-input

I'm quite a newbie (started to learn about coding just like 2 weeks ago) and I'd really appreciate some help to explain why my code isn't working.
I wrote a simple code to calculate the probability. That's not really important part. The code requires some user input so in order to make it kinda foolproof, I wrote two if statements for various kind of wrong input (wrong data type, number too high, number too low) to throw an error message and kill the program. And if the input is right (means none of the conditions of the if statements is true), it should call a function diceTwo(des).
However, if I input number 8 - which should be allright - for some reason that I can't figure out - it triggers the number too high/low if statement, so no matter what number I enter, the function never gets called.

```
cin >> des;

if (cin.fail())
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    cout << "Invalid input! Use only whole positive numbers!" << endl;
    cout << "Try again." << endl;

    return -1;
}

if (des> 12 || des< 1);
{
    cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
    cout << "Remember the only possible values are from 2 to 12!" << endl;
    cout << "Try again." << endl;

    return -1;
}

diceTwo(des);

cout << "The probability of this roll is " << x << "%" << endl;
```

This is the part that makes troubles. I already tried to split the problematic if statement into two (one for <1, one for >12), or adding a new if statement for des>1 && des<12 to call the function, none of it worked. I worked with if statements to provide foolproofness for user input few times before, always worked well, so I really can't seem to find what's wrong this time. Anyone could tell me how to fix it please?

Comment: You do know that `'n'` is not the same thing as `'\n'`, right?

Comment: We need enough code to reproduce the problem. We can't even tell whether `des` is an `int`, a `float`, a `std::string`, or what.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, sure, sorry, my bad, I was cutting out some parts of cout sentences (including \n) to simplify the code as I was putting it here, and probably deleted the '\' by mistake. In my original code it is '\n'. I'll edit it here.

Comment: Please [edit] to provide a [mcve] which includes a copy/paste of **your actual code**, not something you're typing into your post here. Retyping the code can introduce errors that aren't actually part of the problem (as you've just seen). A [mcve] should be able to be copied and pasted into a code editor and compiled without any additional information.

Comment: @KenWhite I'll keep that in mind if I'm posting any question again, this one got solved already. Thank you for advice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a semi colon after the if statement. Look CLOSELY:

```
if (des> 12 || des< 1);   //<----- semi colon
{
    cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
    cout << "Remember the only possible values are from 2 to 12!" << endl;
    cout << "Try again." << endl;

    return -1;
}
```

The semi colon terminates the if statement, so that your program just continues to the next line, which, happens to be your invalid input line. Remove the semi-colon and you're golden :)

Comment: And your compiler should have given you a warning. If it didn't, you're either misusing it or it's a hunk of junk.

Comment: true! you gotta be careful, sometimes your compiler isn't all-knowing

Comment: Oh god thank you! I knew it would be something tiny and stupid that I missed  but not THIS tiny and stupid :D Thank you again. And @DavidSchwartz no, sadly my compiler didn't warn me. I'm using Code::Blocks with default GNU GCC compiler. Is it crappy? Anything better you could recomend me?

Comment: @InsaneNewbie I'd recommend Visual Studio by Microsoft. It's very solid, especially for newcomers. (if you're using Windows, that is)

Comment: @InsaneNewbie Recommended command line add-ons to the GCC family of compilers: `-Wall -Wextra`. Adding on `-Werror` so you can't ignore the warnings has its uses. I also like `-pedantic` because it catches even more, even if it is incredibly... pedantic.

Answer (score 2):

Mistakenly added ; in if

```
 if (des> 12 || des< 1);
```